# Kindle - single gesture / action to go "back"

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, kindle-touch

With touch screen E Ink Kindle devices, is there some way to trigger the back button / action without having to tap twice (i.e. once to trigger the top menu and then again to press the back button)?  I'm not referring to flipping back a page but rather the back button itself which is useful when jumping back to where you were before pressing a link.  I'm using the Voyage but I think if there is an answer it may apply to Paperwhite and the regular Kindle touch too.

Comment: Now that I am heavily using my Paperwhite, this is something which irks me as well quite a lot.  

But I do not think Amazon provides any way to go back with just one tap (they could implement using a particular corner in future perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

No.  I have found no way of doing this with my Paperwhite (and I have tried quite a few things).  This would be very useful to have; perhaps if we suggest it to Amazon, it may become a feature?

Comment: Not sure why an honest answer merits a downvote; there *is not* a way to do this and that's true. I'm sorry if the answer didn't solve your problem.